# WKWebview PDF issue while switching the tab

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have loaded the PDF file in the WKWebview when i switching the tabs in the view then after coming back to WKWebview then PDF is not showing it is showing black color with page numbers but the content of PDF is not displaying.

NOTE: Is it possible without reloading the entire screen again? (I need a better way to fix this issue)

Here is the entire demo (Someone has already made)

https://github.com/aliabbas90/wkwebviewPDF

[image: Here is the video]

Comment: You can use different webviews for tabs.

Comment: please downloard the demo i am not using multiple webview. i just switched the view controllers only (Second tab is just blank view and in first tab there is WKWebview)

Comment: Add        " webView.reloadFromOrigin() " in your viewWillAppear. It will work

Comment: Thank you for your response but i don't want to reload this is just example i have many things binded in original project i can't reload whole view again. is there anything i can do without reload?

Comment: @MayankPatel Did you find a workaround? I am having the exact same behavior issue when switching tabs? Best regards

Comment: @shnaz yes we need to use PDFKit rather then webview and it is but of WKWebview

Comment: This issue is still present in iOS 16 :(

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue. And it seems like it is broken in WKWebView from iOS 12 onwards (even in iOS 13). So, either you reload the data in viewWillAppear or use **PDFKit's PDFView** to render pdf.

But it is for iOS 11 and above. And if your app supports iOS 10 or below, use both because webview works fine for iOS 11 and below.

Just a sample code

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(data: pdfData),
                let pdfView = self.view as? PDFView {
                pdfView.document = pdfDocument
                pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfView.autoScales = true
                pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 4.0
                pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
            }
        } else {
            // load using WKWebView
        }
```

For above mentioned code, just make the view in storyboard as `PDFView` instead `UIView` or make your custom `PDFView`

Answer (score -1):

If you add below code line into viewWillAppear when view is will appear load the pdf content for you.

```
if let pdfURL = pdfURLS  {
   self.webView.loadFileURL(pdfURL, 
                            allowingReadAccessTo: pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
}
```

I think that's solve your issues.

Comment: Why should i reload the page every time? because it is same thing as reload works!